# $ \begin{bmatrix} D_1 & C \\ C^T & D_2 \\ \end{bmatrix} $ always positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Is block matrix of the form $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    D_1 & C  \\
    C^T & D_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$, where $C$ is a nonnegative matrix (entrywise nonnegative) and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal matrix also nonnegative, always positive semidefinite?

If we choose $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that the matrix is diagonally dominant, then we can prove it!!

---

Let $x$ be any vector, partitioned suitably as $x = (x_1\  x_2)^T$. Then $$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^T & x_2^T
\end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    D_1 & C  \\
    C^T & D_2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix} = x_1^TD_1x_1 + x_1^T Cx_2+x_2^TC^Tx_1+x_2^TD_2x_2
$$

Then how should I proceed?

Comment: Is $$\pmatrix{1&7\cr7&1\cr}$$ positive semidefinite?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer/comment?

Comment: Are you still here, userly?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, the determinant is $-1$. Hence it is not positive semidefinite.